# Url amigable por HTACCESS

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

estoy trabajando en PHP puro y quiero trabajar en ajax con urls amigables pero no se bien como configurar el htaccess ni donde ubicarlo.

Que he intentado?

crear el .htaccess con `RewriteRule ^utilities/(.+)\.php utilities/functions.php?function=$1`

pero no se donde ubicarlo, ya que 
tengo lo siguiente, 
`www.dominio.iq/tv/views/administrator/home.iq` ->vista
`www.dominio.iq/tv/js/administrator/functions.js` -> ajax el cual contiene el siguiente código

```
 $.changePassword = function (){
    var parametros = {};
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   '../../utilities/changePassword.php',
        //dataType: "json",
        success:  function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

  }
```

`www.dominio.iq/tv/utilities/functions.php` ->controlador el cual tiene una función

```
<?php
function changePassword(){
      //$oldPassword = $_GET['oldPassword'];
      //$newPassword = $_GET['newPassword'];
     //Y ya lo actualizaria en la bd
     echo "llego";
}
?>
```

entonces la idea es que al yo hacer esto `url:   '../../utilities/changePassword/parametros_1/parametro_2/...parametro_n',`se dirija a `url:   '../../utilities/functions.php`a la fuincion llamada `changePassword()` y que reciba los parámetros que le envié si son necesarios.

Comment: Yo los implemento en la raiz de mi proyecto, no se si sea una buena o mala practica pero me ha funcionado, incluso para configurar redirecciones si la persona intenta acceder a algun sitio donde no exista una web index.html o index.php

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV Yo lo puse prácticamente en todos lados y no funciona me saca error 404

Answer (score 0):

espero mi respuesta pueda ser de utilidad, primero deberías
Evaluar a donde esta apuntando tu servidor web, ejemplo:
 si el dominio **www.tusitio.com** esta apuntando a `/var/www/tusitio.com` es en esa carpeta donde debes tener tu archivo `.htaccess` 
 Por otra parte habría que ver el contenido de tu archivo a ver si posee la configuración que requieres..! en [Esta Web](https://www.bonaval.com/kb/sistemas-operativos/linux-sistemas-operativos/ejemplos-de-htaccess-que-todo-webmaster-deberia-conocer)
hay muchos ejemplos de configuración que te pueden ser de utilidad..!